# Emacs custom building from git

Tags: git, emacs

I have cloned the emacs git repo. What i am trying to do is modify it so that
site-list.el contains a line of code telling emacs to load my custom emacs lib on load. But i would like to do it in a branch so that i can keep up with the bug fixes but every time i build it it gets build with my custom site-lisp file.

But i can not seem to pinpoint where the file is or where it is created?

Comment: Sounds like you merged somewhere, or had your own branch checked out when you pulled updates.

Answer (score 1):

I'd set it up like this:

```
git clone <repository>
git checkout -b my-work  # do all your work on the my-work branch.
<do some work>
git add <list of new files>
git commit
```

When it comes to updating from the remote repository:

```
git checkout master # keep a clean master branch free from your changes
git pull
git checkout my-work
git merge master
```

My point is to take some care to keep a clean branch and a separate development branch.  Also remember **git pull = git fetch + git merge** so you need to take care which branch you have checked out when you pull.

Answer (score 0):

There is a great article on [working with Git from Emacs](http://xtalk.msk.su/~ott/en/writings/emacs-vcs/EmacsGit.html) by Alex Ott introduces the main packages providing an interface for git. Personally I prefer [magit](http://xtalk.msk.su/~ott/en/writings/emacs-vcs/EmacsGit.html#sec12) but in your case I suggest it to you as well, since managing branches is very convenient with it.